# "No parameterless constructor defined for this object." for IBus in controller using StructureMap

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, nservicebus, structuremap

I'm trying to setup StructureMap with NServiceBus.
I've downloaded all the packages and NuGet created some files for me:

[image: New files by NuGet for StructureMap]

Here is the code in those files

IoC.cs:

```
public static class IoC {
    public static IContainer Initialize() {
        var cont = new Container();
        cont.Configure(x =>
                    {
                        x.Scan(scan =>
                                {
                                    scan.TheCallingAssembly();
                                    scan.WithDefaultConventions();
                                });
                        //x.For<IExample>().Use<Example>();
                    });
        return cont;
    }
}
```

StructureMap.cs:

```
[assembly: WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(MyProjectName.App_Start.StructuremapMvc), "Start")]

namespace MyProjectName.App_Start {
    public static class StructuremapMvc {
        public static void Start() {
            IContainer container = IoC.Initialize();
            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new StructureMapDependencyResolver(container));
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new StructureMapDependencyResolver(container);
        }
    }
}
```

Didn't change anything, so those files are the way, they were created.
Then I added a constructor in one of my controllers:

```
public class ProductsController : Controller
{
    private readonly IBus _bus;

    public ProductsController(IBus bus)
    {
        _bus = bus;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Title = "Product list";

        var message = new ProductMessage();
        _bus.Send(message);

        return View();
    }
}
```

That's when I got the error

> No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

which is weird, since this line

```
scan.WithDefaultConventions();
```

should exclude this issue if I'm trying to inject IBus.

What have I already tried:

- Removing [assembly: ...] from StructuremapMvc.cs and calling
  StructuremapMvc.Start() from Global.asax. Same result.
- Added parameterless constructor to the controller with following in
  it's body:

  _bus = _bus = new Container().GetInstance< IBus>();

  but _bus was still null and I got an exception connected to that.

Please assist.

Comment: Pretty straight forward. You need a parameterless constructor on your IBus implementation. If you show the code for that implementation I can specifically show you what you need to do.

Comment: @pquest yes, if I put a prameterless constructor in my controller, the error disappears. But I need the IBus instance in that controller and it doesn't matter if I put it as a parameter or try to resolve it separately, the IBus still cannot be resolved. You can see the implementation above: ProductsController

Comment: What version of `StructureMap` are you using? What NuGet packages & versions do you have installed?

Comment: @XpyM its not in your controller. It is in the IBus implementation

Comment: @NightOwl888 here is the list:
NServiceBus 5.2.14
NServiceBus.StructureMap 5.0.1
structuremap 3.0.5.130
StructureMap.MVC4 3.0.2.115

Comment: @pquest but what exactly should be in that implementation. Do I need to specify some specific class to be used for IBus? Do I need to create that class myself?

Comment: Have you configured NSB to use the right container? See http://docs.particular.net/samples/containers/structuremap/#configuring-nservicebus-to-use-the-container and the `busConfiguration.UseContainer<StructureMapBuilder>(c => c.ExistingContainer(container));` line

Comment: @janpieter_z after some digging, I came to the same solution: I didn't use the correct container when initializing the NSB. Please write your solution as an answer :) thank you all for your help!

Comment: @XpyM done. Glad I could help ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same container for your own code and NServiceBus should be configured. Below code shows this configuration for StructureMap.

```
BusConfiguration busConfiguration = new BusConfiguration();

//Configure the container and use the same one for MVC and NServiceBus    
Container container = new Container();

busConfiguration.UseContainer<StructureMapBuilder>(c => c.ExistingContainer(container));
```

[More information](http://docs.particular.net/samples/containers/structuremap/#configuring-nservicebus-to-use-the-container)